# Getting error trying to login with Cognito in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, amazon-cognito

I'm getting an error when trying to login a user in Expo with Cognito. It works fine in my Next JS application, but not in the mobile.

Here is my login function:

```js
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'
import {
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
    InitiateAuthCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider'
export const userLogin = async () => {
    
    const params = {
        ClientId: 'xxx',
        AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        AuthParameters: {
            USERNAME: 'xxx',
            PASSWORD: 'xxx',
        },
    }
    const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
        region: 'eu-west-2',
    })
    const initiateAuthCommand = new InitiateAuthCommand(params)
    try {
        const response = await cognitoClient.send(initiateAuthCommand)
        
        return res.status(200).json({
        data: response,
        error: '',
        })
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
        data: null,
        error: [err.toString(), JSON.stringify(params)].toString(),
        })
    }
}
```

I get this error:

Failed to construct URL with https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com [TypeError: Cannot read property 'decode' of undefined]